# Dynamic cell reference within a ROW() reference

Tags: excel-formula, row

I need a function in Excel 2013 that returns a dynamic cell reference within a range of cells in a single column.  This must handle anywhere from 2 to 24 rows, depending on the number of months the client is modeling their sales data.

[image]

The cell reference highlighted in red is the cell reference I need to have dynamically referenced in the function.  It appears to be static here, but that is just because it currently refers to the last cell of the current range - $C15.  However, if I were to model 7 or more (or fewer) months, the cell address reference would change accordingly.  I have tried to insert different functions in the `E$15` position, but it always returns a `#VALUE` error.

I have a function that works as I need it to, but I'm using the `ROW()` function to return the cell address of a user-input data.  This user-input data is always the last cell in the column (2-24), but needs to be referenced by the cells above it in order to model the data correctly.

```
=IF(A11=Impact_Over_Months,Retention_Range_Min,IF(A11>Impact_Over_Months,"",(ROW()-ROW(C$10))/(ROW(C$15)-ROW(C$10))*(LOOKUP(2,1/($C$10:$C$33<>""),$C$10:$C$33)-Retention_Range_Max)+Retention_Range_Max))
```

The problem is in this section - `/(ROW(C$15)-ROW(C$10))*`, where the function `ROW(C$15)` has to return the dynamic cell reference to the last row in the data set.

I have tried OFFSET, INDEX, MATCH, and others in different combinations, but to no avail.  Can anyone offer a solution that **does NOT involve VBA**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `ROWS` instead of `ROW` so you can use `INDEX` in an array to get the last entry:

```
ROWS($C$1:INDEX($C:$C,COUNTA($C:$C)))
```

Comment: you can get a nice description of the use of `INDEX` in this way here https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/02/18/excel-index-function/#index-dynamic-ranges

Comment: COUNTA won't work here.  It looks for non-empty cells, but in this case, since a function resides in each cell in the dynamic range, Excel sees the function as a non-empty cell.

I'm going to try using a version of COUNTIF/COUNTIFS...

Comment: Try replace `COUNTA` with `COUNTIF($C:$C,">""")`

Comment: Note that this only works for text. Numbers are ignored in this case.

Comment: I need to have the cell address returned that has a user-input value to it, so COUNTIF won't work either...

Comment: You said that the user-input data is in the last cell. `ROWS($C$1:INDEX($C:$C,COUNTIF($C:$C,">"""))` will give you the row number of the last entry in column C.